# Tkinter: un-focusable window after alt+tab

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've created following class:

```
if sys.version[0] != 3:
   sys.exit(2
else:
   from tkinter import * # pylint: disable =unused-wildcard-import

class Window(Tk):

 def __init__(self,x,y):
    super().__init__()
    self.geometry('%dx%d' % (x,y))

 def update(self):
    super().update_idletasks()
    super().update()

 def cutTitleBar(self):
    self.attributes('-type', 'splash')


mainFrame = Window(100,100) mainFrame.cutTilteBar()

while True:  mainFrame.update()
```

Now to the strange behaviour: when I start the programm: (*python3 tkTest.py*) the created window seems to be locked to the foreground (-> no self.attributes('-topmose', 1) or simmilar stuff is included!). Except when I switch to the terminal the window vanish but can't be refoucsed from this point...(=alt+tab e.g.) (python programm is still running...)

*recently checked: (calling lift() has no impact)*
<s>Do I have to check if Window isn't in Front and then call *lift()*?</s>

```
def foo(self):
 bool = self. #check if in front -> couldn't find such function?
 if bool:
  self.lift()
```

**NEW**: I checked: if state of window is changed when alt-tab (-> invisible):

```
if mainframe.state() != 'normal':
 print('something has happened')
```

with no result... yields also 'normal' even when not visible through alt-tab

**Answers:**
@FrainBr No - AND If you use all of this stuff in an not oo manner all works Like a charm

@acw Take misspelling as not decisive... -> I didn't copy paste the programm: I put this example together exclusivly for Stack overflow

@Bryan - I admit that it is a little bit clunky in **this example**... but the basic idea was: that I wanted controll over when exactly to re-render the frame or in other words if I want to do other stuff in the main loop...

-> but this doesn't change anything to the descriped problem...!

Comment: doesn't `self.geometry` and `self.attributes` throw errors?

Comment: There is an extra `x` in the geometry string.

Comment: Why are you doing `while True: mainFrame.update()`? That is less efficient than calling `mainloop`.